# Ubuntu installation running into errors

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I am using the following system:

Lenovo Legion Y520-151KBM with Windows 10, Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, 256GB SSD + 1TB HDD, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q (6GB).

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my system via dual boot using a USB stick. I clicked the Install Ubuntu option in the grub menu after which I get the Ubuntu desktop. After clicking the Install Ubuntu icon on the desktop and going through the language selection, wifi connectivity and third-party software installation screens, I get this screen for Installation type:

[image]

...which is different from what I should have gotten. After clicking on the Change button, I got this error message.

[image]

I am not able to proceed with my installation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you somehow skipped the simple/automatic setup and instead were asked (on the first screenshot) to specify your partition scheme.  This screen shows no existing partitions, which is weird since you have 2 drives, one with Windows on it in the system.  Is Ubuntu detecting the drives properly?

I don't know how to partition a dual boot.  You should google it.  But for all ubuntu I use:

On fastest drive (SSD/NVME):

```
25GB: Ubuntu mounted at: /
20GB: /swap
Rest of drive: /home
```

Or you could put either `/home` or `/home/Documents` on bigger slower drives if necessary.

To dual-boot with Windows you probably need (this is annoying):

```
1GB (or less): uefi
```

You definitely want a Windows-only partition so you don't blow away your existing OS.

All that said, you probably just want to use the simple setup instead of selecting "let me choose" or "advanced."  Simple setup (I don't know if that's the real name) probably works better in 17.10.

Might be worth using the latest and planning to upgrade to 18.04 LTS in a few months.  I don't know, 17.10 is the buggiest version of Ubuntu in about 7 years, so maybe you're better off with 16.04 after all?

Comment: I had created a free partition of 500GB out of the 1TB HDD to install Ubuntu. Instead of 16.04, I had also tried installing 14.04, where I get a screen like this: https://imgur.com/a/vgtCj . It seems to be a much better result as it shows all my partitions, but in this case the Ubunutu is not able to detect my Windows installation.

Comment: Can the installer see you SSD drive?  For a dual-boot, the bootloader has be able to see your Windows drive/partition, or it's not going to work.

Comment: when I press F12, I do get the options of either booting my windows or booting from my USB

Comment: @user564650 sorry but I'm out of ideas.